# copy row in same table and update just one column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, copy, primary-key, row, duplicates

I need to copy a row based on some condition(where clause), from a table,make a duplicate entry in same table and update just one column(a foreign_key). But because "select * from Table_name" returns all fields including primary_key it is not able to insert new row
error : duplicate key.

I don't know all the columns of table, so i cant ignore primary_key by giving only required column names in select query.

Is there any way to ignore primary_key from fetching itself.. or can i fetch the whole row, and set the primary_key value to null, and then insert the row in table, so that it auto increments the primary_key for new row being added.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to do what you want by querying the information schema tables, and using dynamic SQL to build an appropriate statement.  However, you should take great care with this approach, as modifying data in tables for which you do not know the column names could result all sorts of problems:

```
DROP TABLE mytable;

CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `col1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col3` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO mytable (col1, col2, col3) VALUES ('A', 'B', 'C');

SELECT * FROM mytable;

+----+------+------+------+
| id | col1 | col2 | col3 |
+----+------+------+------+
|  1 | A    | B    | C    |
+----+------+------+------+

SET @columns := (
  SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(column_name)
    FROM information_schema.columns
    WHERE table_schema = 'test'
    AND table_name = 'mytable'
    AND column_key <> 'PRI'
);

SET @sql := (
  SELECT CONCAT(
    'INSERT INTO mytable (', @columns, ') ',
    'SELECT ', @columns, ' FROM mytable ',
    'WHERE id = 1;'
  )
);

SELECT @sql;

+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| @sql                                                                                  |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| INSERT INTO mytable (col1,col2,col3) SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM mytable WHERE id = 1; |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;

EXECUTE stmt;

SELECT * FROM mytable;

+----+------+------+------+
| id | col1 | col2 | col3 |
+----+------+------+------+
|  1 | A    | B    | C    |
|  2 | A    | B    | C    |
+----+------+------+------+
```

Comment: Thanks, Mike.. Why I will not know the column names is because, I am writing a generic stored procedure for performing same kind of operation on several different kinds of table I have. So I will just know the table name and "where clause" to use which is gonna be same for all tables.

Comment: @shailesh: Okay, well the dynamic SQL approach may work for you, but my warning still stands. Good luck :-)

Comment: Hey Mike, It don't seems there is a better alternative.. I am using this.. Thanks again..

Comment: You have used " column_key <> 'PRI' " to keep it from coming in @columns, can we also filter other columns(which we know, and dont want) like this... 
I also have a foreign key in my table which I want to update in newly duplicated row.. I was wondering if I can change it's value even before inserting the new row... As of now.. I will have to update that column after inserting the new duplicate row..

Comment: The [information_schema](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html) contains lots of information that you can use. I think the column_key in information_schema.columns will probably hold the information you need.

Comment: Good, I'm glad it helped.  Now that I know your situation, I've toned down my warning a little.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

if you have knowledge about the sequences of the array you got, then after putting some kind of condition you can ignore field which is having primary key.

Check like this if it works

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How can it be that you know what the key is but don't know what the other columns are? If that's really the case then I think you'll have to write some dynamic SQL - or better still, give the task to someone who *does* know the table structure.